# Jetty how to detect if HTTP connection was closed by client

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

**Problem**

Jetty 9 based server is processing time consuming (30-60 sec) and computation heavy (~20 threads involved in parallel processing) requests.

Due to interactive nature, client may cancel HTTP request after few seconds and send a new one.

It is desirable to cancel computation immediately if connection has been closed by client.

**Unsuccessful attempts**

1. In case of closed HTTP connection, attempt to write to response output stream would trigger `IOException`. Though, in case of this application, HTTP status depends on result of whole computation so it is not possible to write anything back to socket in the middle of processing. Thus, this option is not applicable.
2. Jetty have handy `HttpConnection.getCurrentConnection()` method which can be used to get references to some internal classes related to HTTP connection including underlying `SocketChannel`. Though I haven't found a way to check liveliness of connection though `SocketChannel` or other Jetty's classes related to connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best choice is to use the `javax.servlet.AsyncContext` and its `javax.servlet.AsyncListener`.

Start with a call to `java.servlet.HttpServletRequest.startAsync()` to get the `AsyncContext`.

Then add a custom `AsyncListener` of your own, don't forget to also set a timeout on your `AsyncContext` (as its existence overrides the default Idle Timeout mechanism)

You'll get events that mean something useful to you ...

- **onComplete** - the processing has completed
- **onError** - the processing has failed (such as a unexpected connection termination)
- **onTimeout** - the AsyncContext timeout has fired

This is the mechanism that the Servlet API has provided for exactly your situation: computation or backend heavy processing during an active request that might be terminated early.