# Avoid further processing if client HTTP connection has been closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, http

I'm trying to improve performances and computing costs on a Spring Boot application which handles simple REST requests.

Here is what I would try to achieve:

1. The client (browser) sends an HTTP POST request
2. My server (Spring Boot) receives the request and start executing the related logic.
3. The client loses connection permanently (or the user closes the browser)

At this point, is it possible to stop whatever the server is doing and let it release connection/thread/and whatever resource it has retained for handling the request?

Is there any particular configuration or a specific implementation is needed?

Comment: Take a look at similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234484/jetty-how-to-detect-if-http-connection-was-closed-by-client

Answer (score -3):

It would not be correct to stop the logic because a user will not receive information. Imagine the case where this process applies a necessary or irreversible change. Otherwise, you should further segment the logic that it executes so that it is executed in the event that the user confirms that he is there.

Comment: First, the question states that the client won't receive the response anyways, so this answer is not helpful. Second, retrying interrupted/failed calls is the reason for idempotent endpoints (GET and PUT are idempotent by definition). Third, cancelling blocking calls when the underlying TCP connection is closed is standard practice in Golang (through cancellation of `request.Context()`).